# StrPtr type mismatch in 64 bit mode

Tags: vba, ms-access, 32bit-64bit

I used below code (got it from web site) in Access 2013. It worked without any issue.

```
Private Declare Function GdipCreateBitmapFromFile Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal FileName As Long, bitmap As Long) As Long

If GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(StrPtr(sFileName), hPic) = 0 Then ....
```

After I remove 32 bit component for Access 2013 64 bit run time installation, I get compiler error.  I add PtrSafe after Declare and compiler will be OK.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromFile Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal FileName As Long, bitmap As Long) As Long

If GdipCreateBitmapFromFile(StrPtr(sFileName), hPic) = 0 Then ....
```

But, it will have run time error - type mismatch in StrPtr.  Do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use LongPtr for 64-bit instead of Long.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GdipCreateBitmapFromFile Lib "gdiplus.dll" (ByVal FileName As LongPtr, bitmap As Long) As Long
```